# IS there a webhook for Docusign after all recipients have signed

Tags: docusignapi

I have a workflow where there are 2 signers,  a client, and then a supervisor. I have it so that the client signs it,  then the supervisor signs it.  I now need my app, to get the signed document.

I have been reading some docusign API and some SO stuff and I see this [DocusignRest API](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#Basic%20Scenarios/Retrieving%20Envelope%20and%20Documents.htm?Highlight=documents)

But that is after the envelope reaches completed status,  I don't want to have to poll the envelope,  is there a webhook or callback that I can call after ALL recipients have signed/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, DocuSign has webhook called as DocuSign Connect. You can subscribed for the trigger events like envelope complete etc, once that event happens then DocuSign will push the XML message to you with the envelope details. You can read more related to DS here,

- [Custom Connect Configuration](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/custom-connect-configuration.htm)
- [DS Support - Connect](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-connect)

Answer (score 0):

There is, you can refer to this link: [Docusign Connect](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-connect).
Set triggers in your account:

1. Go to Admin
2. Click "Add Configuration" Dropdown and choose custom
3. Add your webhook URL and set your triggers

see image:
[image]

Comment: Is this only available for Docusign Connect? The regular webhooks (that's free on all plans) lets you subscribe to events, but I didn't see a way to subscribe to specifically Recipient Events. Is this possible for the regular webhooks using eventNotification?

Comment: That I don't know, I haven't tried it outside of docusign connect.

Comment: Found the answer to my own question. Yes, you can use it with the API using eventNotification. Recipient Events is very similar to Document events. I just tried it using the link below as a guide. Basically adding the eventNotification object to your envelope definition and adding in the recipient events along with the webhook URL. Here's the link:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/webhook-status

Answer (score 0):

The Connect event for all signers have signed is Envelope.Completed.

Not all account types include Connect. If your account type does not include connect, then you can create a Connect webhook for a specific envelope, by including the eventNotification object with the Envelopes::create call. This method for initiating connect for an envelope is only available if you use the API to create the envelope.